# Laravel - Validation locale not taking {lang}.json value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

current code:

```
// lang/id/validation.php

return [
  'required' => __(":Attribute") . " wajib diisi.",
]

// lang/id.json
{
    "Password": "Kata Sandi"
}
```

If the password validation failed, it always return `Password wajib diisi` how can I take the `password` value from `id.json` to become `Kata Sandi` (I already make sure the language is ID)?

I know its possible to use the `"custom"` on validation.php, but it will be so many redudant.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your question is a little bit weird. You should not use the translation helper method inside the localization file. Instead, Laravel has provided an `attributes` section inside the `validation.php` file. You can put the password attribute inside the `attributes` section and leave the `required` message as default: `:attribute wajib diisi.`

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad thanks for comment. I want `:attribute` to be translated to the specific lang. I've tried leave it there without __ it will still remain `password`

Comment: You can set an array with `'attributes'` key in `/resources/lang/{lang}` (where {lang} is your locale key) as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779746/7498116).

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thanks! that's what i looking for.